# Mysql comparing value

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the value from my dropdown and compare it to my departmentId row, so when generating report i can simply just call from departments table the departmendId row.

```
<div class="form-group category">
        <label for="category">Departamento: </label>
        <select  class="form-control form-element" name='department'>
        <option selected disabled> --Piliin ang Departamento-- </option>
        <h3><optgroup label="ADMINISTRATIVE SERVICES">  
        <option class='drop-down' value='1'> Office of the City Mayor </option> 
        <option class='drop-down' value='2'> Office of the City Administrator </option>                                         
        <option class='drop-down' value='3'> Human Resources Management Office </option>                                                
        <option class='drop-down' value='4'> Central Records Management Office </option>                                                    
        <option class='drop-down' value='5'> General Services Office </option>
        <option class='drop-down' value='6'> Procurement Office  
    </option>   
        <option class='drop-down' value='7'> Public Information Office </option>
        <option class='drop-down' value='8'> Anti-Graft Board  </option>
        </optgroup>
        </select>
        </div>
```

//this is my dropdown

```
 if (isset($_GET['department']))
        {
            $department=$_GET['department'];
                              }
```

// this is my code of getting the value from dropdown

```
 $depId = "SELECT FROM departments WHERE 'departmentId' = $department";
  $result = mysql_query($depId);
  if($department == $result) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO complain (department,name,address,barangay,complainee,subject,message) VALUES('$result','$fullname','$address','$barangay','$complainee','$subject','$message')";
   $res = mysql_query($query);
   }
```

//this is my code in comparing the value of my dropdown to departmentId row, the value of the departmentId must be in the department row in complain table, when im viewing my complain table, department row it shows nothing.

Comment: you are open to SQL Injection Attack, make use of mysqli or pdo instead of mysql

Comment: this will never true `if($department == $result) {` because you are trying to compare a string with a db result-set object . An please stop using deprecated+removed version of `mysql_*` . turn to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statements`.

Comment: i do set the value of my dropdown to int so i can easily compare the value of my dropdown to my departmentId row. if($department == $result), this is what im trying to do if(1 == 1) then condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First correct SQL `SELECT` query must be

```
SELECT * FROM departments WHERE departmentId = $department;
```

Then you need to fetch value of `departmentId` using one of the `mysqli_fetch()` statement and finally compare it with `$department`.As below.

```
 $depId = "SELECT * FROM departments WHERE departmentId = $department"
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,$depId);//$connection is database connection object
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 if($department == $row['departmentId']) {
     $fullname = $row['fullname'];
     $address = $row['address'];
     $barangay = $row['barangay'];
     $complainee = $row['complainee'];
     $subject = $row['subject'];
     $message = $row['message'];
     $query = "INSERT INTO complain (department,name,address,barangay,complainee,subject,message) VALUES('$department','$fullname','$address','$barangay','$complainee','$subject','$message')";
     mysqli_query($connection,$query);
 }
}
```

Comment: i get an error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE).

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\helpdesk1\content\complain.php on line 110

Comment: try using `mysqli` not mysql because mysql_* is depricated now and will removed from php 7

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\helpdesk1\content\complain.php on line 109

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\helpdesk1\content\complain.php on line 110

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in your query change your select query as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM departments 
WHERE departmentId = $department;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
$depId = "SELECT FROM departments WHERE 'departmentId' = $department";
```

with

```
$depId = "SELECT * FROM departments WHERE departmentId = '$department'";
```

use

```
var_dump(...);die();
```

for each level of your code for ease. for example:

```
 $depId = "SELECT * FROM departments WHERE 'departmentId' = $department";
 var_dump($depId);die();
```